# How to discard non compliant version of Android app "Ready to send for review " on production track?

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-app-bundle, google-play-internal-testing

Currently the play console prevents us from publishing a compliant version on the internal test track.

The reason seems that we have a non compliant version also "Ready to send for review" on the production track (build 206, cf picture).[image: changes ready to send for review]

Everytime we send for review these changes, the non compliant version gets rejected. This is expected, but the problem is that it blocks the review of the compliant version on the test track.

Google play support says publishing a new compliant verison on the production track should solve the problem. But we'd like to publish this compliant version on a test track first.

How can we cancel or discard the non compliant version on the production track ?

Is there an other solution ?

Comment: were u able to get around this @matdev ?

Comment: were you able to get around this? Google instructed to make sure to deactivate the non-complaint version before publishing the new one, but there is no option to deactivate the version that had been already submitted for review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to just upload a new app bundle and after submitting it for review it replaced the non-compliant app bundle. Google's support told me to deactivate the old app bundle before uploading the new one, which is misleading, as there doesn't seem to be such an option in Play Console. Hope it helps.

[old version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpZBy.png)
[new version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yknmw.png)